# Java Replacing Help Needed

Tags: java

Hey guy's so am trying to replace all characters and numbers to get the /hello/what/ only without the REMOVEThis4.PNG i don't want to use string.replace("REMOVEThis4.PNG", ""); cause i wanna use it on other strings not only that

Any help is great my code

```
String sFile = "/hello/what/REMOVEThis4.PNG";
if (sFile.contains("/")){
    String Replaced = sFile.replaceAll("(?s)", "");
    System.out.println(Replaced);
}
```

I want the the output to be

/hello/what/

Only thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use regular expressions in your case:

```
String sFile = "/hello/what/REMOVEThis4.PNG";
// TODO check actual last index of "/" against -1
System.out.println(sFile.substring(0, sFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

**Output**

```
/hello/what/
```

**Note**

In case you are dealing with actual files, you can probably spare yourself the `String` manipulation and use `File.getParent()` instead:

```
File file = new File("/hello/what/REMOVEThis4.PNG");
System.out.println(file.getParent());
```

**Output** (may change depending on your system)

```
\hello\what
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to parse a path, I recommend to find the last index of `/`, and get the substring to this index plus one. So

```
string = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: Was about to suggest this, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's `File` API:

```
String example = "/hello/what/REMOVEThis4.PNG";
File file = new File(example);
System.out.println(example);

String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
System.out.println(filePath);
```

Comment: if you said "use File API", you could have used it :) Hint: `file.getParent()`.

Comment: How does using the File make this any better than the other answers using the substring/lastIndexOf technique?

Comment: @forgivenson For one, you get platform independence; for two, you want the path to access an actual file, anyway.